# How can the original Logger be grafted/inherited by cement

Tags: python, command-line-interface

I use cement to develop a CLI for the Python Modules.
The original Modules use

```
import logging
MODULE_LOGGER = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

to generate the log.
How can I import/grafte/inherit(sorry, as a noob I don't know the professional word) the original logger into the application log and use `log handler` to generate log by cement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Minimal_logger can be used.
The Code is as follows:

```
from cement.utils.misc import minimal_logger 
LOG = minimal_logger(__name__)
```